# Angularjs: How to correctly compile a custom directive inside a factory?

Tags: angularjs-directive, slickgrid

I have a custom angular directive called list.

```
<my-list data-enabled="true" readonly data-selected-item="value"></my-list>
```

And I have a factory that is used as formatter/renderer provider for Slickgrid.

```
module.factory('gridCellRenderers', gridCellRenderersFactory);

gridCellRenderersFactory.$inject = ['$log', '$compile', '$rootScope', '$timeout', 'extGridConstants'];

function gridCellRenderersFactory($log, $compile, 
$rootScope, $timeout, extGridConstants) {

var newScope = $rootScope.$new(true, $rootScope);
var _preCompiledComboList = $compile('<my-list data-enabled="true" readonly data-selected-item="value"></my-list>')(newScope);

 var _cellComboListRenderer = function(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext){
   _preCompiledComboList[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].setAttribute("value", value);
   return _center(_preCompiledComboList[0].outerHTML);

   };
}
```

Currently the directive is precompiled and used inside my listrenderer. And **selectedItem** property of directive is set using JS which I do not want.

Therefor, I compiled my directive inside my _cellComboListRenderer function like this:

```
var _cellComboListRenderer = function(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext){

    var newScope = $rootScope.$new(true, $rootScope);
    var comboListDir = $compile('<my-list data-enabled="true" readonly data-selected-item="' + value +'"></my-list>')(newScope);
    return comboListDir[0].outerHTML;

};
```

And set the **selectedItem** to be cell value. But now the problem is, the directive is not compiled anymore. it shows nothing on grid, but when look at chrome console, I see:

```
<my-list data-enabled="true" readonly data-selected-item="cellvalue"></my-list>
```

Now the question: Why the first version compiles correctly my directive, but not the second version?